# Performance of MySQL vs CSV vs .txt for retrieving all of the data

Tags: java, mysql, database, csv

I'm developing a song recommender system using last.fm dataset. The dataset consists of 1 million JSON files with each file having the details about one song. I'm thinking to shift the dataset either to MySQL databse or a CSV file or a TXT file.

To recommend a song, i'll need the data of all the other songs. So basically i'll have to retrieve all the data stored. So where should the data be stored to give the minimum retrieval time?

I know that Databases are designed to store and retrieve data efficiently when we are retrieving a subset of the stored data and in most of the cases it ts the better choice compared to a CSV or a TXT file. But in this case, If i'm storing the data in MySQL database, then to retrieve the data, i'll be firing only `select * from table` queries. Would that give any advantage over storing the data as CSV or TXT file?

It is going to be a Java web application on Tomcat server.
Even if I use MySQL database to store and retrieve the data, i'll be querying for a million entries. Are there chances of running out of the memory error? In case of CSV or TXT file, i'll be reading the files line by line. So there will not be any out of memory error.

Things to consider:

- The data is static. Once the data is stored, data will only be read.

  Data of all songs is required. However, data of only one song is required at a time.

  MySQL database is local. So there is no bandwidth overhead.

  I'll be using `BufferedReader` in case of reading from either CSV or TXT file

Comment: Q: Where should the data be stored to give the minimum retrieval time? A: In a tree in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you do in fact need all the data, all the time, and there are no relations -- then an RDBMS is not what you need, as you have already discovered.

A TXT or CSV is fine.